# Button input width attribute not working

Tags: html, css, forms, button, input

My code for a button wont work.  My goal is to get the width longer, but it has no effect.    Here is a snippet of code from it, where the errors should be:

```
    <form action="http://kindust.com/test.html">
    <input type="submit" value="Shop" width="150">
    </form>
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything to it

Comment: 1. What are you trying to make wider? 2. Close your input tag. 3. Use CSS.

Comment: @Fiddles Cool, you could've added that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CSS

```
    .btn{
       width: 150px;
    }
```

### HTML

```
<form action="http://kindust.com/test.html">
    <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Shop">
</form>
```

Comment: Or you can skip the class and use `input[type=submit]`. No need to add classes to everything all the time.